# Implementing Submit action in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to javascript..I am facing some problems while trying to implement form submit action onclick using javascript..

> The problem is when I implement all the validation checks using if-else conditions ..The function dose not produce any result..

[[image: Here is the pic when the validation checks are not implemented]]  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TVLy.png)[[image: Here is the pic when the validation checks are implemented]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3Q2c.png)

I have implemented various validation check and tried to capture all possible form elements with different conditions..But I am failing when I am implementing validation check..otherwise the code works -I cannot figure out what is the problem..

Here is the code:

```js
function submitForm() {
  var nam = document.getElementById("student_name").value;

  if (nam.length == 0 || !(isNAN(nam)) || nam.length > 20) {
    nam = "Invalid";
  }

  var ag = document.getElementById("student_age").value;

  if (ag.length == 0 || isNAN(ag) || ag.parseInt() > 100) {
    age = "Invalid";
  }

  var gender = document.getElementById("g1").value;

  if (document.getElementById("g1").checked) {
    gender = document.getElementById("g1").value;
  } else if (document.getElementById("g2").checked) {
    gender = document.getElementById("g1").value;
  } else {
    alert("You must select a gendrer!!");
  }

  var cty = document.getElementById("city").value;

  var pan = document.getElementById("h1").value;
  var dan = document.getElementById("h2").value;
  var sprt = document.getElementById("h3").value;

  if (document.getElementById("h1").checked) {
    var pan = document.getElementById("h1").value;
    pan = pan + "#";
  } else {
    pan = "";
  }
  if (document.getElementById("h2").checked) {
    var dan = document.getElementById("h2").value;
    dan = dan + "#";
  } else {
    dan = "";
  }
  if (document.getElementById("h3").checked) {
    var sprt = document.getElementById("h3").value;
    sprt = sprt + "#";
  } else {
    spt = "";
  }

  var hobbies = pan + "" + dan + "" + sprt
  document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = nam; //document.getElementById("student_name").value;
  document.getElementById("age").innerHTML = ag; //document.getElementById("student_age").value;
  document.getElementById("gd").innerHTML = gender;
  document.getElementById("ct").innerHTML = cty; //document.getElementById("city").value;
  document.getElementById("hb").innerHTML = hobbies; //document.getElementById("h1").value;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>MyTest</title>
</head>

<body style="background:pink;">

  <div id="body">

    <form>
      <br><br>
      <span id="name_label" style="background:yellow;">Student Name</span> <input type="text" id="student_name" style="background:yellow;"> <br><br>
      <span id="age_label" style="background:yellow;">Age</span> <input type="text" id="student_age" style="background:yellow;"><br><br> Gender <input type="radio" value="male" name="gender" id="g1">M
      <input type="radio" value="female" name="gender" id="g2">F<br>

      <br><br> City
      <select id="city">
        <option value="Delhi">Delhi</option>
        <option value="Mumbai">Mumbai</option>
        <option value="Kolkata">Kolkata</option>
        <option value="Chennai">Chennai</option>
      </select><br><br>

      <label>Hobby </label> <input type="checkbox" id="h1" value="Painting">Painting
      <input type="checkbox" id="h2" name="cbox" value="Dancing">Dancing
      <input type="checkbox" id="h3" name="cbox" value="Sports">Singing
      <br><br>



    </form>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="student_submit" onclick="submitForm()">

    <div>
      <label>Name:</label><span id="name"></span><br>
      <label>Age:</label><span id="age"></span><br>
      <label>Gender:</label><span id="gd"></span><br>
      <label>City:</label><span id="ct"></span><br>
      <label>Hobbies:</label><span id="hb"></span><br>

    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: ___I am facing some problems while trying to implement form submit action___  - What is the problem ?

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] (e.g. reduce the code down to only deal with a form with a single input) and a clear problem statement ([I am failing](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/) tells us very little).

Comment: You should [learn how to use the label element properly](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/). Without a for attribute or a form control inside it, a label is useless.

Comment: You have already accessed value here -  `document.getElementById("student_name").value` and again you are trying to access `value` property in validation statement.

Comment: hi @Rayon I have shown the error

Comment: @Quentin..I have re-editted the code..But still the problem persists

Comment: I have got it found an error and fixed it

Answer (score 0):

The first error is at these lines

```
var nam=document.getElementById("student_name").value;

                if(nam.value.length==0 || !(isNAN(nam)) || nam.value.length>20){
                    nam="Invalid";
                }
```

`nam` is the value of the input again doing `nam.value` will throw an error

Secondly `isNAN` is not a javascript inbuilt function. Case matters while using in build function , it has to be `isNaN`

Thirdly `ag.parseInt()` is wrong. Instead it has to be `parseInt(ag,10)` where 10 is the radix

```js
function submitForm() {
  var nam = document.getElementById("student_name").value;

  if (nam.length == 0 || !(isNaN(nam)) || nam.length > 20) {
    nam = "Invalid";
  }

  var ag = document.getElementById("student_age").value;

  if (ag.length == 0 || isNaN(ag) || parseInt(ag, 10) > 100) {
    age = "Invalid";
  }

  var gender = document.getElementById("g1").value;

  if (document.getElementById("g1").checked) {
    gender = document.getElementById("g1").value;
  } else if (document.getElementById("g2").checked) {
    gender = document.getElementById("g1").value;
  } else {
    alert("You must select a gendrer!!");
  }

  var cty = document.getElementById("city").value;

  var pan = document.getElementById("h1").value;
  var dan = document.getElementById("h2").value;
  var sprt = document.getElementById("h3").value;

  if (document.getElementById("h1").checked) {
    var pan = document.getElementById("h1").value;
    pan = pan + "#";
  } else {
    pan = "";
  }
  if (document.getElementById("h2").checked) {
    var dan = document.getElementById("h2").value;
    dan = dan + "#";
  } else {
    dan = "";
  }
  if (document.getElementById("h3").checked) {
    var sprt = document.getElementById("h3").value;
    sprt = sprt + "#";
  } else {
    spt = "";
  }

  var hobbies = pan + "" + dan + "" + sprt
  document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = nam; //document.getElementById("student_name").value;
  document.getElementById("age").innerHTML = ag; //document.getElementById("student_age").value;
  document.getElementById("gd").innerHTML = gender;
  document.getElementById("ct").innerHTML = cty; //document.getElementById("city").value;
  document.getElementById("hb").innerHTML = hobbies; //document.getElementById("h1").value;
}
```

```html
<div id="body">

  <form>
    <br><br>
    <span id="name_label" style="background:yellow;">Student Name</span> <input type="text" id="student_name" style="background:yellow;"> <br><br>
    <span id="age_label" style="background:yellow;">Age</span> <input type="text" id="student_age" style="background:yellow;"><br><br> Gender <input type="radio" value="male" name="gender" id="g1">M
    <input type="radio" value="female" name="gender" id="g2">F<br>

    <br><br> City
    <select id="city">
      <option value="Delhi">Delhi</option>
      <option value="Mumbai">Mumbai</option>
      <option value="Kolkata">Kolkata</option>
      <option value="Chennai">Chennai</option>
    </select><br><br>

    <label>Hobby </label> <input type="checkbox" id="h1" value="Painting">Painting
    <input type="checkbox" id="h2" name="cbox" value="Dancing">Dancing
    <input type="checkbox" id="h3" name="cbox" value="Sports">Singing
    <br><br>



  </form>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="student_submit" onclick="submitForm()">

  <div>
    <label>Name:</label><span id="name"></span><br>
    <label>Age:</label><span id="age"></span><br>
    <label>Gender:</label><span id="gd"></span><br>
    <label>City:</label><span id="ct"></span><br>
    <label>Hobbies:</label><span id="hb"></span><br>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry @brk ..it was my mistake to enter `nam.value.length` it was originally `nam.length` in the code but still did not work

Comment: please validate the other two defects mention in the code

Comment: it is not implementing validation at all..is there anything wrong in the logic?

Comment: @brk I trtied to implement it locally -But none of the validations are working

Answer (score 0):

This might help you

```js
function submitForm() 
{
  var nam = document.getElementById("student_name").value;

  if (!(nam) || nam.length > 20) 
 {
  alert("please Select a valid name");
  return false;
 }

  var ag = document.getElementById("student_age").value;

  if (!(ag) || ag > 100) 
  {
    alert("please Select a valid age");
  return false;
  }

  var gender = "";


  if(!document.getElementById("g1").checked && !document.getElementById("g2").checked )
 {
  alert("please Select gender");
  return false;
 }
 else
 {
  if(document.getElementById("g1").checked)
  {
   gender = document.getElementById("g1").value;
  }
 else
  {
   gender = document.getElementById("g2").value;
  }
 }

  var cty = document.getElementById("city").value;
 if (!(cty) || cty=="Default") 
 {
  alert("please Select a city");
  return false;
 }

  var hobbies ="";
  if(!document.getElementById("h1").checked && !document.getElementById("h2").checked  && !document.getElementById("h3").checked)
 {
  alert("please Select hobby");
  return false;
 }
 else
 {
   var inputElements = document.getElementsByName("cbox");
   for(var i=0; inputElements[i]; ++i){
         if(inputElements[i].checked){
           var value=" "+ inputElements[i].value;
              hobbies  +=value;
         }
   }
 }

  document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = nam; //document.getElementById("student_name").value;
  document.getElementById("age").innerHTML = ag; //document.getElementById("student_age").value;
  document.getElementById("gd").innerHTML = gender;
  document.getElementById("ct").innerHTML = cty; //document.getElementById("city").value;
  document.getElementById("hb").innerHTML = hobbies; //document.getElementById("h1").value;
  

  return true;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>MyTest</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script> 
</head>
<body style="background:pink;">

  <div id="body">

    <form action="#" method="post" onsubmit="return false">
      <br><br>
      <span id="name_label" style="background:yellow;">Student Name</span> <input type="text" id="student_name" style="background:yellow;"> <br><br>
      <span id="age_label" style="background:yellow;">Age</span> <input type="text" id="student_age" style="background:yellow;"><br><br> Gender <input type="radio" value="male" name="gender" id="g1">M
      <input type="radio" value="female" name="gender" id="g2">F<br>

      <br><br> City
      <select id="city">
  <option value="Default">Select City</option>
        <option value="Delhi">Delhi</option>
        <option value="Mumbai">Mumbai</option>
        <option value="Kolkata">Kolkata</option>
        <option value="Chennai">Chennai</option>
      </select><br><br>

      <label>Hobby </label> 
  <input type="checkbox" id="h1" name="cbox" value="Painting">Painting
  <input type="checkbox" id="h2" name="cbox" value="Dancing">Dancing
  <input type="checkbox" id="h3" name="cbox" value="Sports">Singing
      <br><br>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="submitForm()">
    </form>

    <div>
      <label>Name:</label><span id="name"></span><br>
      <label>Age:</label><span id="age"></span><br>
      <label>Gender:</label><span id="gd"></span><br>
      <label>City:</label><span id="ct"></span><br>
      <label>Hobbies:</label><span id="hb"></span><br>

    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```